# Using Function Templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have created a structure of different data types and i want to return each type of data. does this can be done using a function template which takes a different data argument not included in structure or no arguments?

I have something like this,

```
struct mystruct{
int _int;
char _c;
string _str
};

In function template(int i)
{
     mystruct s;

      switch (getInput)
     {
      case 1:
        return s._int;
      case 2:
        return s._c;
      case 3:
        return s._str;
   }   
} 

void main()  

{
   int getInput = 1;
   //pass getInput value to function template
}
```

Comment: It would help to add an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What is a structure of different data types? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want, can you explain in more detail? A function template allows you to implement generic functions and if so desirable specialized variants for certain data types.

Comment: I think he needs a variant type. He can always warp his brain around Boost variants. Or, for added fun, he can use `void*` as a pointer to whatever.

Comment: Would it be possible to put this in more context? Like, what you need to do as a goal?

Comment: Boosts variants don't help if you're dealing with C-compatible scripting interfaces (`NPVariant`, COMs `VARIANT`, ...).

Comment: @Dave: are you actually looking to write a conversion function for some variant data type?

Comment: no, I just specified the return template parameter to get the desired type from the function.

Comment: I don't know why not write three parameterless functions instead of one with a "switch" parameter.

Comment: @Dave: Why do you need to use templates then instead of wrapping it in class with accessors or using free functions like `get_str(mystruct& s)` ?

Comment: yes that is right, I guess I just wanted to see how convenient they are to use instead of writing many functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
template<class T>
T f() {
  return 0; // for the sake of example
}

int main() {
  return f<int>(); // specify the template parameter
}

template<class T>
vector<T> another_example();
// use another_example<int>() which returns a vector<int>
```

Comment: I bet it has nothing with templates to do at all ;) I'll give you +1 anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

The following is building of GMan's (now deleted) interpretation of your very confusing question:

```
struct some_data
{
    int i;
    char c;
    std::string s;
};

template< typename T > struct Getter;
template<> struct Getter<int> { static int& get(some_data& data) {return data.i} };
template<> struct Getter<char> { static char& get(some_data& data) {return data.c} };
template<> struct Getter<std::string> { static std::string& get(some_data& data) {return data.s} };

template< typename T >
inline T get(some_data& data) {return Getter<T>::get(data);}
```

I'm not sure. though, whether this is what you were asking for.

Comment: +1 Almost exactly what I was writing up. (P.S. I'm deleting my answer since yours is best, you should remove the link to mine.)

Comment: I'm not sure this is right, because it seems he wants to determine the type at runtime (I'm basing this on *getInput* meaning input from the user); but as we know, that isn't possible.  You can also specialize *get* directly, since it doesn't require partial specialization.

Comment: I guess I would go with using the return f<typename>(); specifying the return type at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is the following: I want to create a function whose return type depends on its parameter(s). Well, technically, you can't.

1. When those return types are classes with a common ancestor, you could return a pointer to that ancestor. It's not quite the same thing, but it works. Unfortunately, two of the return types are `char` and `int`, which are not classes in first place.
2. When those return types are plain old data types, you could return a tagged union. Unfortunately, one of the return types is `std::string`, which is not a plain old data type.
3. A solution that works with any type but is incredibly hacker-ish is to use `void*`. Well, unfortunately, `void*` is error-prone. Whoever maintains your code will curse you forever if you use `void*`.
4. A final solution (pun not intended) that works is to use `boost::variant`. It's quite complicated, but at least it's safe (unlike `void*`), because type errors can be checked at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another interpretation that doesn't use templates:

```
struct some_data
{
    int i;
    char c;
    std::string s;

    void get(int& value) const
         { value = i; }
    void get(char& value) const
         { value = c; }
    void get(& value) const
         { value = s; }
};

// ...
some_data received_data;
int k;
received_data.get(k);
//...
received_data.s = "Hello";
std::string world;
received_data.get(world);
std::cout << world << std::endl;
```

The compiler will generate the correct method calls based on the type of the argument.
This can be translated into non-member functions:

```
void Get_Some_Data(char& value, const some_data& sd)
{
    value = sd.c;
    return;
}


void Get_Some_Data(int& value, const some_data& sd)
{
    value = sd.i;
    return;
}

void Get_Some_Data(std::string& value, const some_data& sd)
{
    value = sd.s;
    return;
}

//...
char f;
Get_Some_Data(f, received_data);
```